# inkscape pattern re-name

Tags: inkscape, patterns

I have no problem using the XML editor of Inkscape 1.2, since it's well-explained, but when I rename the pattern, the image I've imported goes blank, and also the list of patterns goes blank

screenshot before
[image]

screenshot after
[image]

I'm using Windows 7

Can someone correct what I've done wrong...

Answer (score 1):

You're not renaming the pattern, you're changing which pattern is referenced by the object, meaning it now tries to use an undefined pattern.

You have to both change the pattern `id`-attribute inside the `<defs>`-tag and fix the reference on the object.

It's probably faster and easier to use the 'Edit → Find/Replace...' dialog. Enter the pattern name without the leading '#', set it to 'Search in Properties' and make sure 'ID' and 'Attribute value' are checked in the options.

Comment: Thanx for the correction...